# MongoDB Aggregate how to sum values in object array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I'm trying to add up two amounts within an object inside an Aggregate pipeline.

Here's my sandbox: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LIvksL-UGur

Document:

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "invoices": [
        {
          "product": "baseball",
          "amount": 4,
          "tax": 1
        },
        {
          "product": "basketball",
          "amount": 10,
          "tax": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I would like the result to be:

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "invoices": [
        {
          "product": "baseball",
          "amount": 4,
          "tax": 1,
          "total": 5
        },
        {
          "product": "basketball",
          "amount": 10,
          "tax": 2,
          "total": 12
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here's what I thought would work:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "result.invoices": {
        "total": "$result.invoices.amount + $result.invoices.tax"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The total is empty because it's trying to add two arrays, which I understand by trying this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "result.invoices": {
        "total": "$result.invoices.amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

...which gives this:

```
[
  {
    "result": {
      "invoices": [
        {
          "product": "baseball",
          "amount": 4,
          "tax": 1,
          "total": [
             4,
             10
           ]
        },
        {
          "product": "basketball",
          "amount": 10,
          "tax": 2,
          "total": [
             4,
             10
           ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

How do I do it the right way?

Note: I realize this is a very simple example, and I can add the calculation after getting the results. This just illustrates a more complex problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `result.invoices` is an array field, you need to use `$map` to iterate through the elements and use `$mergeObjects` to append the `total` field there.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "result.invoices": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$result.invoices",
          "as": "i",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$i",
              {
                "total": {
                  $sum: [
                    "$$i.amount",
                    "$$i.tax"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SCudJ9T38AY)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      "result.invoices": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$result.invoices",
          "as": "invoice",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$invoice",
              {
                "total": {
                  "$sum": [
                    "$$invoice.amount",
                    "$$invoice.tax"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lz7jzjcLIWz) for a working example.